# Having a hard time getting Api from localhost?

Tags: javascript, api, server

I am on this project wherein I need the api from this specific software. I cannot fetch it when I am trying to fetch it, sometimes error 404 are occuring,
sometimes no-cors policy.
Then sometimes like this: GET http://localhost:8000/events/1003/results net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
getEvents @ orbiter.js:22
(anonymous) @ orbiter.js:28
Then sometimes Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:

There are no authorization that needed based on the documentation or headers. Or i thought so it does not have?
But i think this is because of the way that I am fetching the API, it looks like I am doing it wrong. The API as i am trying to get on the instruction on the documentation it says i can access it on "localhost"

At first i just need to open the software to have access on the localhost so the http port will open, then i go to "localhost" then everything is on that local host

This are the picture [Screenshot of The LocalHost I need to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbKzb.png)

Now based on this I need to get the result of the event. Based on the documentation I need to go to path "localhost/events/{event-id}/results" then a json format would be send back to me.

I go to the url using browser using that path and I get the result, [This are the result based on that path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNmbV.png) but this are the thing, when I am trying to put it on the code using Javascript language es6 module wherein I am fetching the api and I put the link "localhost/events/{event-id}/results"

this are the code:

```
const link = "http://localhost/events/1003/results";
async function getEvents() {
  const response = await fetch(link);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

getEvents();
```

I cannot access now the data that I needed from the API. Even though the path on the link that I put was correct. Am i missing some steps here? That's all. As you can see, localhost is the main path, then i just follow the path based on the documentation to get the results. (Because what i need to access are the results of the events). Then errors has occurred. This are the documentation that may help you to help me. I hope some of you may help me on this one as I'm still a beginner on programming

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1Il6GPL-pqxeS8OWVOEt36OF-a_FfQwpj

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Il6GPL-pqxeS8OWVOEt36OF-a_FfQwpj?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am askin if im calling the api in the right way. what i want is to access the events/event-id/results of the current localhost. but i don't know where i would start.